# Как делать блоки такого вида?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3, svg

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Каким образом лучше всего делать блоки такого вида?

Чтобы при масштабировании форма была адаптивна и текст не выходил за границы блока.

Comment: Конечно проще всего на `SVG` нарисовать полигон, но я так понял вас интересует именно `HTML`+`CSS`?

Comment: @St1myL, можно и SVG, главное что бы адаптивно было это дело

Comment: @uzi_no_uzi добавлен новый ответ

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Решение SVG

*Решение адаптивно, работает во всех браузерах.*
Текст и знак параграфа находятся внутри блока SVG, поэтому никогда не нарушится их взаимное положение и текст не выйдет за пределы блока при любом изменении размеров окна браузера. Рамки и текст будут изменяться пропорционально.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="-10 -10 500 500"> 
    <polygon points="0,0 50,0 65,15 160,15 160,100 0,100" stroke="gray" fill="none" />
    <text x="10" y="30" font-size="24" fill="gray">&#167;</text>
    <text x="30" y="35" font-size="14" fill="black">TYPOGRAPHY</text> 
    <g font-size="12" fill="gray">
      <text x="15" y="50">Lorem ipsum dolor sit,</text>
      <text x="15" y="62">amet consectetur adipisicing </text>
      <text x="15" y="74">adipisicing elit Phasellus </text>
      <text x="15" y="86">tincidunt dignissim nibh</text>
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>
```

**Второй вариант блока с тенью**

- Для реализации тени под первый полигон добавляем второй полигон и
  смещаем его на `2px` вправо и вниз: 
  `<polygon transform="translate(2 2)"`
- Чтобы тень не выглядела грубо, размываем её фильтром Гаусса -
  `feGaussianBlur`

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="-10 -10 500 500">
    <defs>
      <filter id="dropshadow" width="130%" height="130%">
        <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="4"/> 
        <feOffset dx="2" dy="2" result="offsetblur"/> 
      </filter>
    </defs>    
    <polygon transform="translate(2 2)" points="0,0 50,0 65,15 160,15 160,100 0,100" fill="rgba(0,0,0,0.5)" filter="url(#dropshadow)"/>
    <polygon points="0,0 50,0 65,15 160,15 160,100 0,100" stroke="gray" fill="white" fill-opacity="1"/>
    <text x="10" y="30" font-size="32" fill="gray">&#167;</text>
    <text x="35" y="35" font-size="14" fill="black">TYPOGRAPHY</text> 
    <g font-size="12" fill="gray">
      <text x="15" y="50">Lorem ipsum dolor sit,</text>
      <text x="15" y="62">amet consectetur adipisicing</text>
      <text x="15" y="74">adipisicing elit Phasellus</text>
      <text x="15" y="86">tincidunt dignissim nibh</text>
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

## Решение на `CSS`:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 250px;
  margin: 3rem;
  padding: 1rem;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

.angle,
.in,
.in2,
.in2::before {
  position: absolute;
  height: 30px;
}

.angle {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 160px;
  top: -30px;
  left: -1px;
}

.in {
  top: 0;
  left: -10px;
  width: 150px;
  background-color: gray;
  transform: skew(25deg);
}

.in2 {
  top: 1px;
  left: 1px;
  width: 130px;
  background-color: white;
}

.in2::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  right: -8.4px;
  width: 25px;
  background-color: white;
  transform: skew(25deg);
}

.text {
  max-width: 350px;
  word-spacing: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="angle">
    <div class="in"></div>
    <div class="in2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    <h1>Lorem</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Porro necessitatibus deleniti perspiciatis excepturi quia facere? Porro necessitatibus deleniti perspiciatis excepturi quia facere?</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

## Решение на `SVG`:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

h2 {
  margin: 1rem 0.3rem 0 0.3rem;
}

p {
  font-size: 13px;
  padding: 0 0.3rem;
} 
.container {
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="-10 -10 500 500">
  <polygon points="0,0 50,0 65,15 130,15 130,100 0,100" stroke="gray" fill="none"/>
  <foreignObject width="150">
    <h2>Lorem</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
  </foreignObject>
</svg>
</div>
```

Comment: а как адаптировать это? Будет ли оно адекватно реагировать на размеры заданные в относительных величинах вроде % и тд.

Comment: @uzi_no_uzi, насчёт `SVG` сам не слишком уверен, но можно попробовать вынести svg-код в отдельный файл, а затем добавить его как `background` для основного блока допустим.

Answer (score 2):

CSS и clip-path:

```css
.block,
.block:before {
   clip-path: polygon(0 0, 50% 0, 70% 20%, 100% 20%, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
   z-index: -1;
}
.block {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: black;
  position: relative;
}

.block:before {
  content: '';
  width: 198px;
  height: 198px;
  background: white;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1px;
  left: 1px;
}
.inner {
  padding: 50px 10px 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="block"><div class="inner">Lorem text</div></div>
```